# No resource or method named powershell for Chef::Recipe

Tags: powershell, chef-infra

When I run the powershell script on chef -solo on local  System ,it give below error message. I have already added powershell in cookbook,

```
NoMethodError:-------------
No resource or method named `powershell' for `Chef::Recipe "M3"'

Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  C:\chef\cookbooks\Balasahebb\recipes\M3.rb:44:in `from_file'

Relevant File Content:
----------------------
C:\chef\cookbooks\Balasahebb\recipes\M3.rb:

 37:  #Write the output status of the commands to C:\auto\runstatus in the forma
t status:success or status:failed
 38:
 39:  template "c:\\auto\\zib.conf" do
 40:    source "csb_automaticmssql_configuration.erb"
 41:    #variables({:hostname => "#{HOSTNAME}"})
 42:  end
 43:
 44>> powershell "create configuration directory and copy conf" do
 45:    code <<-EOH
 46:  Backloc=(Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Zman
da\ZIB).BackupSetLocation
 47:  mkdir "#{Backloc}\#{BACKUPSET}"
 48:  CP 'c:\\auto\\zib.conf'  "#{Backloc}\\#{BACKUPSET}\\zib.conf"
 49:
 50:    EOH
 51:    action :run
 52:  end
 53:


Running handlers:
[2015-07-15T13:50:01+05:30] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2015-07-15T13:50:01+05:30] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 20.512517 seconds
[2015-07-15T13:50:01+05:30] FATAL: Stack trace dumped to C:/chef/cache/chef-stack
trace.out
[2015-07-15T13:50:01+05:30] FATAL: No Method Error: No resource or method named `p
power shell' for `Chef::Recipe "M3"`enter code here`'
```

Comment: Can you show us how you declared a dependency on the powershell cookbook in your metadata.rb file?

Comment: Thnx ...i'll add dependency in maetdata

Comment: Reposted as an answer. Would appreciate, if it's correct, if you would mark it as such :)

Answer (score 1):

You should add `depends 'powershell'` to your `metadata.rb` file, if you want that resource available. This is assuming you are using the powershell community cookbook, and not just looking for the `powershell_script` resource that comes with Chef.